# How do I extract content from a webpage with certain headers in bash?

Tags: html, bash, curl, w3m

So far I am using `curl` along `w3m` and `sed` to extract portions of a webpage like `<body>`....content....`</body>`. I want to ignore all the other headers (ex. `<a></a>`, `<div></div>`). Except the way I am doing it right now is really slow.

```
curl -L "http://www.somewebpage.com" | sed -n -e '\:<article class=:,\:<div id="below">: p' > file.html 
w3m -dump file.html > file2.txt
```

These two lines above are really slow because `curl` was to first save the whole webpage into a file and phrase it, then `w3m` phrases it and saves it into another file. I just want to simply this code. I was wondering if there was a way with `lynx` or `hmtl2text` that lets you extract webpage content with specified headers. So like if I wanted to extract something from as webpage (www.badexample.com <---not actually the link) with this content:

```
<title>blah......blah...</title>
            <body>
                 Some text I need to extract
            </body>
 more stuffs
```

Is there a program which i can specify the parameter in which to extract the content? So I would specify `someprogram <body></body> www.badexample.com` and it would extract the content only in those headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perl's one liner for this:

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "print get ($ARGV[0]) =~ /<$ARGV[1]>(.*?)<\/$ARGV[1]>/;" http://www.example.com/ title
```

Instead of the html tag, you can pass the whole regex as well:

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e "print get ($ARGV[0]) =~ /$ARGV[1]/;" "http://www.example.com/" "<body>(.*?)</body>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Must it be in `bash`? What about `PHP` and [`DOMDocument()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.domdocument.php)?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$new_dom = new DOMDocument();

$url_value = 'http://www.google.com';
$html = file_get_contents($url_value);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
  $new_dom->appendChild($new_dom->importNode($child, true));
}

echo $new_dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. The thing is I haven't learned PHP yet (I have plans to), and the program I am writing is a bash script (mainly for information processing). It's not that your answer is not sufficient, it's just that I don't know how to use it. But I'm pretty sure someone else can use it if they see this solution! THanks so much!